# Upload multiple file being resized showing only one preview

Tags: jquery, image, file-upload, resize, filereader

Without utilizing any extra plugins, I'm doing a image upload for multiple files with drag_n_drop and preview functions. Further I'll create a custom element in my project for it. I could accomplish all the required functions, but when I try to upload two files with almost the same size (1.4xMB and 1.8x MB) it shows only the last one selected. If I try with huge differences it works.

Jquery for when the file input gets any change.

```
$(document).on('change', '.upload-resizable input[type="file"]', function () {
    var file;
    var $parent = $(this).closest('.upload-resizable');
    for (var i = 0; i < this.files.length; i++) {
        if (file = this.files[i]) {
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = function (e) {
                var img = new Image();
                img.onload = function () {
                    var ratio = Math.min(800 / this.width, 600 / this.height);
                    var width = this.width * ratio;
                    var height = this.height * ratio;

                    var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
                    canvas.width = width;
                    canvas.height = height;
                    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
                    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, width, height);

                    var dataUrl = canvas.toDataURL();

                    var cell = $parent.find('.upload-cell.stay-in.hidden').clone();
                    cell.removeClass('hidden').removeClass('stay-in');
                    cell.find('img.upload-preview').attr('src', dataUrl);
                    $parent.find('.upload-box').append(cell);

                    var hidden = $parent.find('input[type="hidden"]');
                    if (hidden.val() != "") dataUrl = hidden.val() + "|" + dataUrl;
                    hidden.val(dataUrl);
                };
                img.src = e.target.result;
            }
            reader.readAsDataURL(file);
        }
    }
});
```

I need the `new Image` part, for the resize.
When I use `console.log(file.name)` after/before `reader.readAsDataURL(file);` the names are different (what is expected) but if I print the `e.target.result` it puts a delay on the code, making the preview images being differents (what should be, but without this delay, it doesn't happen).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing `img.src = e.target.result;` to `img.src = this.result;` inside the `reader.onload` did the job!